# Angular: How to get smaller size on file angular app?

Tags: angular

This is my image:

[optimize file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOqVk.png)

Can anyone help me get smaller size to all of them. I'm very confused

Comment: Building your app will produce much smaller files. https://angular.io/start/start-deployment#building-locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can split your bundle by lazy loading, it decrise size of main app bundle and helps you to speed up your app

See https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 1):

You will have a much lower size in prod build.

```
ng build --prod
```

If you want to speed up your app in general. There are many ways to do it.

- Use Angular 9.x that provides a nice tree shaking to avoid bundling full libraries.
- Use some compression at your static production server. GZIP for example.
- Use [PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) technology
- Consider using SSR ([Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal))

And many others

Comment: can i use all of those methods on Angular v6?

Comment: @FarhanAlfiy You can use GZIP compression definitely because it does not depend on Angular. Other technologies also can be implemented in some way in Angular 6 but it will be not rationally at all and will take much time from developers. It's more efficient to migrate to the latest version of Angular and get more other nice features. After migration, you will be able to add PWA with one console command and tree shaking out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have useless dependencies.
You can check it if you exec command "ng build --stats-json" this command build your app and create json stats file in dist folder.
If you want see all dependencies in your build app you should use this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer or alternative.

e.g: sometimes developers install lodash lib use few functions, but in app bundle have all library